# React — open modal in body from nested component

Tags: reactjs

React noobie... I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way to handle modals in a React App... i.e. where the modal container should live and where the children should live and whether I should use state or props to handle the open/close. Also, how to open them relative to the document body no matter where they live.

**My overall App structure:**

```
<App>
  <Sidebar />
  <MainConstainer>
    <ChildPage>
      <ChildList>
        <BtnModalTrigger>
          <button onClick={open.modal.relative.to.doc.body}>Open Modal</button>
        </BtnModalTrigger>
      </ChildList>
      <Modal />
    </ChildPage>
  </MainConstainer>
</App>
```

I have the Modal component in the child page hidden, and the trigger button in the list and then the "Close modal" button is in modal itself. I'm not sure where to put my isOpen and isClosed functions or how to pass the onClicks up and down the component tree.

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGjv-p9jYf0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This is fantastic... this video is just what the doctor ordered. Totally helpful. Thank you!